# Getting Error while implementing Proguard in App

Tags: java, android, proguard

This is what I'm getting when I added Proguard to the app. It is given the error of null parameter.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: throw with null exception
at com.alldaydr.clinician.ui.b.a.a.b(Unknown Source:3)
at com.alldaydr.clinician.ui.login.d.b$d.f(VerifyPhonePresenter.kt:91)
at com.alldaydr.clinician.ui.login.d.b$d.e(VerifyPhonePresenter.kt:26)
at f.b.r.e.a(Unknown Source:2)
at f.b.o.d.c.f(LambdaObserver.java:63)
at f.b.o.e.b.j$a.k(ObservableObserveOn.java:201)
at f.b.o.e.b.j$a.run(ObservableObserveOn.java:255)
at f.b.k.c.b$b.run(HandlerScheduler.java:124)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
```

Answer (score 0):

Disable the obfuscation so you can check which methods are causing the error. Add the following to `proguard-rules.pro`

```
-dontobfuscate
-optimizations !code/simplification/arithmetic,!field/*,!class/merging/*,!code/allocation/variable
-keepattributes *Annotation*
```

Run again, then you can see the the error instead of obfuscation `ex: ui.b.a.a.b`

Comment: It is throwing java.lang.NullPointerException on a parameter which is already initialised

Comment: ```java.lang.NullPointerException: throw with null exception
2020-10-15 17:05:39.831 18051-18051/com.alldaydr.clinician.dev W/System.err:     at com.alldaydr.clinician.ui.auth.model.User.getEmail(Unknown Source:3)```

Comment: check if the user object you're calling getEmail on is initialised

Comment: It is already initialized when I remove proguard It is running perfectly